# How can I use XCode 4 to build an application that uses py2app?

Tags: xcode, py2app

Recently I finally figured out how to package a Python app ([Mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org/)) using py2app.  This is cross-platform software and py2app pulls in a lot of dependencies-- PyQt, cherrypy, etc.-- so re-writing is not an option.

However, if possible, I would like to submit this application to the App Store or at least sign the code so that when Mountain Lion is released next month users will be able to install it without a warning.  However, when I launch Xcode (I've never used it before), I am prompted to choose a template and I have no idea what to choose.

I can easily build the application like this:

> sudo python setup.py py2app

Could someone give me a rough idea of the things I have to do in order to be able to build this instead in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Xcode to sign the .app. You can also use the standalone command called codesign (that's code-sign, not co-design). Once you've created your .app, you can sign it using a command such as

```
codesign -s "Your Developer ID Profile Name Here" "Your Program.app"
```

You'll need to read the man pages to figure out what options you need exactly, but hopefully this at least points you in the right direction. Also, you obviously need to have your Developer ID certs etc in your keychain for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used py2app, but I can give you a rough idea of what you have to do to build your app in Xcode. Start by creating an external build system project. An external build system project allows you to use Python's tools to build the project.

After creating the project, you may need to configure the build tool to build the project properly. Select the project file from the project navigator on the left side of the project window. This opens the project editor. Select your target on the left side of the project editor. Click the Info button at the top of the editor to configure the build tool.